# jQuery validation engine custom javascript validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I am trying to validate the availability of a subdomain with the jQuery Validate Engine through a custom function. Validation appears to happen correctly but the alertText is not displayed if .ajax request returns 200. I have added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers and can see the request completing successfully in my logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Javascript Function:

```
function validateDomain(field, rules, i, options) {
    var url = "https://" + field.val() + ".example.com/";
    $.ajax(url,
        {
            statusCode: {
                200: function() {
                    //alert('name exists already');
                    return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Form Field:

```
    <label class="required" for="signup[subdomain]">Subdomain<span>*</span></label>
    <span>https://</span>
    <input id="signup[subdomain]" name="signup[subdomain]" class="field field validate[required,funcCall[validateDomain]]" type="text">
   <span>.example.com</span>
```

Comment: can you add a error handler and see whether it is getting executed, my doubt is a parse error is occuring

Comment: looks like a duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

Comment: You've tagged this both [tag:jquery-validate] and [tag:jquery-validation-engine] and yet these are two totally different plugins.  Which one are you really using?

Comment: Sparky has edited the correct plugin. I am using jquery-validate-engine. @Bergi This is what I needed. Adding a callback for the request works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `$.ajax` is a asynchronous function and don't work this way.

```
function validateDomain(field, rules, i, options) {
    var url = "https://" + field.val() + ".example.com/";
    $.ajax(url,
        {
            statusCode: {
                200: function() { // [ second function ]
                    return options.allrules.validate2fields.alertText;
                }
            }
        });
}
```

The problem is: your return is only for the `[second function]` not for `validateDomain`.

Looking at the docs of [jquery-validation-engine](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/blob/master/README.md) I can't see a way of doing what you want.